# SQL Server 2019 Extensibility Framework vs Postgres Extensions

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

Is SQL Server 2019 Extensibility Framework is the equivalent of Postgres extensions. I think both are NOT exactly same based on below articles.

what is the exact difference between these two.

https://www.postgresql.eu/events/pgconfeu2019/sessions/session/2641/slides/265/Implementing%20your%20first%20PostgreSQL%20extension.pdf

https://nielsberglund.com/2019/06/06/sql-server-2019-extensibility-framework--external-languages/

Answer (score 0):

At a glance they are not very similar.  The [PostgreSQL extensions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend.html) appear more similar to [SQL Server CLR Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/introduction-to-sql-server-clr-integration) as a means to extend the database engine with functions, procedures, types and aggregates (plus more extensibility points in PostgreSQL), running inside the database engine.

The SQL Server Extensibility Framework is a way to run custom code *outside* the database engine, through a special stored procedure [sp_execute_external_script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-external-script-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).  The emphasis is on safely supporting multiple languages (Python, R, Java, C# (.NET Core)) with permissive permissions and bring-your-own libraries, intenteded primarilly for machine learning applications that need to bring compute close to the data, but not necessarily *inside* the database engine.

Comment: A Postgres extension is more than just a collection of functions or types. It can also intercept the query execution and the optimizer, e.g. to support distributed queries (Citus is one example and owned by Microsoft in the meantime). Postgres procedures/functions an also be written in Python or R

Comment: That's what I meant by the "and more", ie that PostgreSQL supports more engine extensibility points.  Clarified answer.

Comment: I dont think CLR is similar to extensions.   CLR can be similar to Postgres functions written in Python/Perl

Comment: SQL CLR provides custom data types and custom aggregates in addition to functions and stored procedures.